# TYPO3 ckeditor: allow img tag without enabling image plugin

Tags: ckeditor, typo3

On a plain TYPO3 8 installation, I want ckeditor to allow the img tag in the source, without enabling the image plugin. The default configuration of ckeditor in TYPO3 removes the image plugin, which causes img tags to be removed as well.

According to the ckeditor documentation, this can be achieved with the property

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'img'
```

but it does not work in my custom yaml configuration. img tags are always striped when I switch from source to wysiwyg mode.

If I enable the image plugin, img tags are kept. But I do not want to give to the editors this button as an option.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my test yaml configuration. At the bottom is the extraAllowedContent option

```
imports:
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml" }
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Base.yaml" }
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml" }
editor:
  config:
    contentsCss: ["EXT:rte_ckeditor/Resources/Public/Css/contents.css", "EXT:tucmmforumhook/Resources/Public/Styles/Tucmain.css"]
    stylesSet:
      - { name: "XYZ Text", element: "span", attributes: { class: "highlighted red"} }
      - { name: "Button", element: "a", attributes: { class: "button"} }
      - { name: "Checklist", element: "ul", attributes: { class: "check-list"} }
    format_tags: "p;h2;h3;h4;h5"
    toolbarGroups:
      - { name: styles, groups: [ styles, format ] }
      - { name: basicstyles, groups: [ basicstyles ] }
      - { name: paragraph, groups: [ list, indent, blocks, align ] }
      - { name: links, groups: [ links ] }
      - { name: clipboard, groups: [ clipboard, cleanup, undo ] }
      - { name: editing, groups: [ spellchecker ] }
      - { name: insert, groups: [ insert ] }
      - { name: tools, groups: [ table, specialchar ] }
      - { name: document, groups: [ mode ] }
    justifyClasses:
      - text-left
      - text-center
      - text-right
      - text-justify
    extraPlugins:
      - justify
    removePlugins:
      - image
    removeButtons:
      - Strike
      - Anchor
      - Outdent
      - Indent
      - Blockquote
      - JustifyBlock

    extraAllowedContent:
      - img
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @ikon answer, I managed to make the extraAllowedContent to work. Instead of

```
extraAllowedContent:
  - img
```

it was enough to use

```
extraAllowedContent:
  - img[!src,alt,width,height]
```

This keeps the img tags intact, without needing the image plugin

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you need to switch to the custom mode of AFC:
https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acfcustom.html .

Use:

```
allowedContent: 
- img[!src,alt,width,height]
```

to allow images.
It might be tricky than to make configuration/filtering fitting to your presets: you have to add other allowed tags to `allowedContent`list as well, otherwise the buttons for tables, list etc would not be rendered.

**Avoid** using

```
allowedContent: true
```

because it would allow everything!

Comment: Thanks for the response @ikon. First of all, let me say that your approach leads to the correct result, but as you point our yourself, I would have to add a lot more configuration settings for all my tags. Given your response, I managed to make the extraAllowedContent configuration work. Basically, specifying img only was not enough, and I had to add the rest of your example. I will add an answer to this question myself.