# Typo3/CKEditor: Allow definition list (dl, dt, dd)

Tags: ckeditor, typo3

this question is driving me crazy. I'm using typo3 (8.7.13) with CKEditor as the RTE. Now I want to allow to use `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` in the source code view mode. But every time I leave the source code view those tags become modified to `<p>`

`<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` are lsited in the yaml file under

```
processing:
  allowTags:
    - dl
    - dt
    - dd
```

And within the template constants i set:

```
styles.content.allowTags := addToList(dd)
styles.content.allowTags := addToList(dt)
styles.content.allowTags := addToList(dl)
```

What more is necessary?

fins wimmer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I finaly found the solution based on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422412/typo3-ckeditor-allow-img-tag-without-enabling-image-plugin?rq=1).

This needs to be inserted in the yaml config:

```
editor:
  config:
    extraAllowedContent:
      - dd
      - dl
      - dt
```

fin swimmer

Answer (score 2):

I've found a [plugin for ckeditor](https://github.com/Reinmar/ckeditor-plugin-descriptionlist) (which not only allows `<dl>` tags and so forth but also provides custom buttons for the editor) and created a simple wrapper extension to easily integrate that into TYPO3. In case anyone's interested it's on github as [rte_ckeditor_dl](https://github.com/kitzberger/rte_ckeditor_dl).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work ?

```
RTE.default {
    allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
    proc {
        allowTagsOutside := addToList(dd,dt,dl)
    }
}
```

[documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/rtehtmlarea/DefaultConfigurations/Default/Index.html)

Comment: Hello webMan, thanks for your answers. Sadly this doesn't work either. I guess this way of configuration just works for the old RTE htmlarea (as your link to the documentation is for that RTE) and not for CKEditor.

Comment: hmmm.. it does work because I have it working, but there must be more to it ... I can look tonight ...

Comment: There's a small typo in `addToList(dd,dt.dl)`. Replace the dot with a comma and check again.

Comment: Yes, I saw this typo and already corrected it. But it still doesn't work. I also do a new clean installation of typo3 to make sure, that nothing of my other configurations,extension,.. make some strange behaviour. But with no success :(

Answer (score 0):

Do your own configuration for CKEditor as YAML and add

```
processing:
  # Tags that are allowed in the content in general
  allowTags:
    - dd
    - dl
    - dt

  ## Tags that are allowed outside of paragraphs
  allowTagsOutside: [dd, dl, dt]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this doesn't work for me :( I created a new `yaml` file, import the `Default.yaml` at the beginning and added your code afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

editor:
   config:
      allowedContent: true

[..]

processing
   allowTags:
      - dl
      - dt
      - dd

Comment: Hello loon, perfect. This works as well. Could you please explain what's the difference between your and my solution?

Comment: "allowedContent: true" .. don't ask why, its typo3. ;)

Comment: no; i searched for different solutions for this new editor. ..and finally i can say - this editor solution is an absolute mess! ..if you want to configure you can't use typoscript - no, you need to use yaml. ..if you want to customize your own editor layout - you can't use typoscript - no, you need to setup an extension. if you want to kill this oldschool "pixel" diktat or kill the ungrateful preprocess-image setup from the ckeditor-image extension - you can't use typoscript - no you need to override the whole javascript.. i mean wtf? ..who nerdy you can be to write an cms-editor for 2001? :/